# Border color in a bgcolor

Tags: pine-script

I have this code

```
bgcolor(z > c and z > f ? green : z < c and z < f ? red : yellow, transp=70)
```

I want to add a border with a different color.
I try set_border_color but don't works.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

`bgcolor` does not have a `border_color` argument. You can try using a `box` instead.